# PLSQL - update with random month and day while keeping year

Tags: sql, date, plsql

I'd like to update all birthday in the table with different random month and days.

The following sql works fine

```
update PERSON set bithday = TO_DATE(TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '1940-01-01','J') ,TO_CHAR(DATE '1940-12-31','J'))),'J') ;
```

but the year stays in 1940.
To keep the initial birthday year I modified the sql like this

```
update PERSON set bithday = TO_DATE(TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE ''||extract(year from bithday)||'-01-01','J') ,TO_CHAR(DATE ''||extract(year from bithday)||'-12-31','J'))),'J');
```

but this gives me an error

```
01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
*Cause:    Illegal year entered
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure for such a simple update?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the way you use `DATE`; if you need to get a date from a string, you have to use `to_date`, and not `DATE`.

For example, this works

```
SQL> select date '2018-01-01' from dual;

DATE'2018
---------
01-JAN-18
```

but

```
SQL> select date '2018-' || '01-01' from dual;
select date '2018-' || '01-01' from dual
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month


SQL> select date extract(year from sysdate) || '-01-01' from dual;
select date extract(year from sysdate) || '-01-01' from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression


SQL> select date '2018' || '-01-01' from dual;
select date '2018' || '-01-01' from dual
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string


SQL> select date '''' || extract(year from sysdate) || '-01-01' from dual;
select date '''' || extract(year from sysdate) || '-01-01' from dual
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
```

About your need, this could be an easier solution:

```
update person    
set birthday = trunc(birthday, 'YEAR') + mod(abs(dbms_random.random), 365)
```

Comment: Thanks but still not working
    update PERSON set bithday = TO_DATE(TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(extract(year from bithday)||'-01-01','J')) ,TO_CHAR(DATE ''||extract(year from bithday)||'-12-31','J'))),'J');

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with people not being born on Dec 31 of leap years, a simple method is:

```
select trunc(bithday, 'YYYY') + trunc(dbms_random.value * 365) * interval '1' day
```

This easily goes into an `update`:

```
update PERSON
    set bithday = trunc(bithday, 'YYYY') + trunc(dbms_random.value * 365) * interval '1' day;
```